# Как добавить обработчик события propertieschange на кластер?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandexmapkit, yandex-geocoding-api

Как добавить обработчик события propertieschange на кластер?

Есть кластер

```
 const cluster = new ymaps.Clusterer({
  ...options,
  clusterIconContentLayout: clusterLayout(ymaps),
});
```

И внешний список объектов. При наведении на объект необходимо вызвать анимацию на карте для корректного кластера.

В clusterLayout хочу добавить анимацию, но не понятно, на чем завязаться

```
this.getData().geoObject.events.add('propertieschange', () => {...});
```

Не работает, так как скорее всего не получается изменить properties у кластера

```
 const сluster = clusterInstance.getClusters()
      .find(({ properties }) => properties.get('geoObjects')
        .find(({ properties }) => properties.get('id') === id));
    сluster.properties.set({ active });
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим?

Comment: А можете минимальный пример собрать? Не понятно, откуда у вас clusterInstance, если ранее сluster вы объявляете как кластеризатор и именно в нём должен работать  .getClusters(). Также не совсем ясно, зачем вы хотите менять и искать изменение свойств, если по описанию требуется именно менять опции кластеров по примеру https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_icon_hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Clusterer нету properties, это событие и не должно срабатывать.
А вообще, в документации Яндекса как раз есть похожий [пример](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_icon_hover)

В примере цвет кластера меняется при наведении. Завязано на события mouseenter и mouseleave

Comment: Да, инициализировал события mouseenter и mouseleave при наведении на элемент списка.